# Cocos2d-x Android app not responding until back button pressed

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have an Android app coded in Cocos2d-x. At launch, it often doesn't respond to any taps or presses until I press the back button.

Sometimes on app relaunch, the screen remains blank.

Any suggestions?

Comment: please explain in brief ... you are launching your app using eclipse ? are you testing on emulator or real device ??

Comment: i'm testing on real device